# variable with number doesnt work in alert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to alert a variable that has numbers stored in it. But while trying to display the value via alert it doesnt work. I took a string and saved it in an array as a I wanted to get he individual elements out of the string. So I split the string, save the number parts into the separate variables then used `Number();` to convert the string to numbers.

code for the js

```
dur = $('#time_duration').text(); // string that prints as "Duration:xyhr:xymin"
// dur1 = dur.replace("Duration", "");
// alert(dur1);
var dur_ar = new Array();
dur_ar = dur.split(":");
dur1 = dur_ar[1].replace("hr", "");
dur2 = dur_ar[2].replace("min", "");
dur1_num = Number(dur1);
dur2_num = Number(dur2);

//dur_total = dur1_num . ":" . dur2_num;
// a1 = Number(dur1) . ":" . Number(dur2);

a1 = (dur1_num . ":" . dur2_num);
alert(a1);
```

What I expected `alert(a1);` to show was something like `12:26`
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Try `+` instead of `.` to concatenate..... `dur_total = dur1_num +  ":"  +  dur2_num;`

Comment: `(dur1_num + ":" + dur2_num);` should be

Comment: the `.` is used in PHP to string concatenation - but not in JS where `+` is used

Comment: oh it was that simple haha. got it, works fine thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `php` concatenation while `javascript` concatenation requires `+` instead of `.`

```
a1 = (dur1_num + ":" + dur2_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use backtick sign `` ` ``:

```
a1 = `${dur1_num}:${dur2_num}`;
```